# How can I use insecure urls (http) in React Native WebView in Expo SDK?

Tags: http, react-native, webview, expo

I'm creating a iOS app using the [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app) tool. For login, I'm using the webview component to visit an existing login webpage run from a local docker container. The Webview shows this error whenever I try to visit that page:

> Error loading page
>
> Domain: NSURLErrorDomain
>
> Error Code: -1202
>
> Description: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connection to a server that is pretending to be "local.website.dev" which could put your confidential information at risk.

I found [this site](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/07/27/open-non-https-sites-in-webview-in-react-native.html) explaining how to solve this issue using plist files, but I can't edit these files in my app without ejecting from Expo, which I am reluctant to do.

Is there another way to allow a http site that will work in the Expo SDK environment?

Answer (score 0):

Expo enables `NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` by default. Are you able to visit your `local.website.dev` URL in Safari? If Safari can connect to the website, then Expo should be able to as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to connect to the site in Safari and Chrome.  I think you're right that NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads is true by default, but I think you also have to explicitly add the site as a NSExceptionDomain